# How to write a bash script to set up working environment?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, automation

I want to write a bash automation script to set up my working environment. Like every day I need to open 7 tabs of the terminal with each service running different command and I also open eclipse and various other applications like postman and other things, now I want to automate all this, means writing a bash script to do all of this. I just don't know how to do this. I'll greatly appreciate if anybody can help me out with this.

I have tried writing a command file like this

file1.command

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo mongod
```

but then I'll have to write 7 other command files for each command and others for opening applications, Is it possible with a single bash file to open number of tabs in terminal with each running different command and open applications.

Thanks

Comment: For terminal-based programs, you should spend some time researching [tag:tmux] and/or [tag:screen] (install those with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)). For GUI apps, right click the icon in the dock, "Options" -> "Open at Login".

Comment: Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttab

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Thank you so much, that's what I was looking for. Amazing!